# Vector calculus example

Tags: calculus, vectors

It is given constant $a\in \mathbb R ^3$ and two vector fields:

$b(x)=x$ and $v(x)=\frac{x}{| | x |  |^3 } $, $x\in \mathbb R^3$, $x\neq0$
Calculate: $div(a \times b)$  and $div $ $v$.

I know how to calculate $div$ and cross product generally, but I am not sure what here are excatly $a$,$b$ and $v$?

Can I for example write $a$ as $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$? What about $b$ and $v$?

Comment: $\;a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)=a_1i+a_2j+a_3k\;,\;\;b(x)=(x,y,z)=xi+yj+zk\;$

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbf x = (x_1,x_2,x_3)\\
v(\mathbf x) = \frac {\mathbf x}{\|\mathbf x\|^3}\\
\nabla\cdot v(\mathbf x) = (\nabla\cdot\mathbf x)\|\mathbf x\|^{-3} + \mathbf x\cdot\nabla\|\mathbf x\|^{-3}\\
{3}\|\mathbf x\|^{-3} - 3(\mathbf x\cdot \mathbf x)\|\mathbf x\|^{-5}\\
0$

$a\times b = a_2x_3 - a_3x_2, a_3x_1-a_1x_3, a_1x_2 - a_2 x_1\\
\nabla \cdot (a\times b) = \frac {\partial}{\partial x_1}(a_2x_3 - a_3x_2)+\frac {\partial}{\partial x_2}(a_3x_1-a_1x_3)+\frac {\partial}{\partial x_3}(a_1x_2 - a_2 x_1) = 0$

Comment: Great, I think I understood. Can you help me with similiar example. I started like you, but I dont know how to calculate it to the end. Example: $curl$ $v=?$. My idea: $curl v=\nabla \times v=x(\nabla \times | | x |  |^{-3}  )+(\nabla \cdot x)\times | | x |  |^{-3}=x\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + 3 \times | | x |  |^{-3} $. I dont know how to calculate the last step, how to do cross product of constant with x?

Comment: Intuitively, all of the vectors of $\mathbf v$ point (directly) away from the origin.  There is no curling... $curl \mathbf v = \mathbf 0.$  If all of the vectors in a field are centripetal, the curl is always 0.

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is a constant 3-vector (see the first given) so yes, you can write it as 
$(a_1,a_2,a_3)$.

$\vec{b}(\vec{x})$ is a function of a 3-vector ( as indicated by the statement that  $x\in\Bbb R^3$) that returns a 3-vector value: $\vec{b}((x_1,x_2,x_3)) = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

(I have written the vector sign to emphasize the nature of the three-component objects, but of course you could write $a$ rather than $\vec{a}$ and so forth.)

$\vec{v}(\vec{x})$ is a different function of a 3-vector  that returns a 3-vector value: $$\vec{v}((x_1,x_2,x_3)) = 
\left(\frac{x_1}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^{3/2}},\frac{x_2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^{3/2}},\frac{x_3}{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)^{3/2}}\right)$$

So for example, $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}$ would be a scalar function of a vector argument such that $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3$.